# 電子ペーパーHATの表示を行いたいがエラーが出ています．

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Raspberry Pi，Python初心者です．
Raspberry Piで電子ペーパー（Waveshare 2.13inch e-Paper HAT）の表示をするため，
ユーザーマニュアルを読みながらデモコードを表示させようと行っています．

行った作業は以下の通りです．
ユーザーマニュアル通り，デモコードの入ったファイルを/bootから/home/piに入れた後，

```
cp -r /boot/RaspberryPi/ ./
sudo chmod 777 -R RaspberryPi/
```

Python3のライブラリをインストールして，

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python-imaging
sudo pip3 install spidev
sudo pip3 install RPi.GPIO
sudo pip3 install Pillow
```

表示を試したのですが，

```
cd ~/RaspberryPi/python3 #enter example directory
sudo python3 main.py #running
```

エラーが出てしまいました．

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import epd2in13b
  File "/home/pi/RaspberryPi/python3/epd2in13b.py", line 51, in <module>
    import epdconfig
  File "/home/pi/RaspberryPi/python3/epdconfig.py", line 48, in <module>
    SPI = spidev.SpiDev(0, 0)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Raspberry PiとPythonを触り始めたばかりなのでわからないことばかりなので，どうかよろしくお願いします．読んでいただきありがとうございます．

環境
Raspberry Pi Zero W
Raspbian
Python3
URL:[User Manual](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/4/4a/2.13inch-e-paper-hat-b-user-manual-en.pdf)

[追記]
まずSPI通信を有効にしました．
また，配布のデモコードファイルに
bcm2835,WiringPi,Python2,Python3それぞれに対応したファイルが入っていたので
それらのライブラリをインストールし，runningすると，
bcm2835,WiringPiはデモコードが動作したのですが，
Pythonで動作させようとすると，できませんでした．

```
sudo python3 main.py #running
e-Paper busy
e-Paper busy release
Clear...
e-Paper busy
e-Paper busy release
Drawing
traceback.format_exc():
%s Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    font20 = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-microhei.ttc', 20)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 238, in truetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(font, size, index, encoding)
OSError: cannot open resource
```

ここで手詰まりになってしまいました．
どのような助言でもいいので，よろしくお願い致します．

Comment: こちらのスレッドが参考になりそうです [spi.open(0,0) IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory - Raspberry Pi Forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=154317) / まず、 `ls /dev/spi*` の実行結果を追記していただけますか？

Comment: 反応していただきありがとうございます．`ls /dev/spi*`を試した結果は以下です．`ls: '/dev/spi*' にアクセスできません: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません`

Comment: ＠PicoSushi　さん，ユーザー名を書き忘れてしまったので書かせて頂きました．

Comment: 日本語での「やってみた」記事がいっぱいあるので参考に。[Raspberry Piでe-Paper（電子ペーパー）を動かして日本語を表示する方法](http://asukiaaa.blogspot.com/2018/04/raspberry-pie-paper.html)、[RaspberryPi上のPythonから電子ペーパー(e-Paper)を制御する](https://qiita.com/akrian/items/6a01a5922b71020db1d2)、[Raspberry Piで電子ペーパー／電子インクを使う](https://technoledge.net/raspberry-pi-epaper/)、[7.5インチ epaper(Eペーパー)ディスプレイとラズパイを接続して表示させてみる](https://densi.biz/7-5inch-epaper)

Comment: @kunif　ありがとうございます．記事を参考にして試してみます．

Comment: 該当のフォントファイルを入手・インストールする [2.13 epaper display problem](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=231680) （ただし表示は解決していないようですが）か、該当行を既に存在するフォントファイル名に書き換える [電池が切れても消えないディスプレイって？電子ペーパーを使ってみた！](https://dotstud.io/blog/using-e-paper-module/), [Raspberry Pi で電子ペーパーを点けてみる (e-Paper )](https://qiita.com/jp_yen/items/98d92aad45bac80d7d1a) か、してください。何かの操作で置き換わったりするようですね。[system fontが汎用CJKになっていた](https://matoken.org/blog/2018/05/21/system-font-was-a-general-cjk/)

Comment: @kunif 該当のフォントファイルをインストールしたら表示することが出来ました！初心者ゆえ拙い文など申し訳ない内容だったと思いますが，色々と教えていただきありがとうございました．助かりました！

Answer (score 0):

- 該当のフォントファイルを入手・インストールする
  [2.13 epaper display problem](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=231680) （ただし表示は解決していないようですが）
- 該当行を既に存在するフォントファイル名に書き換える
  [電池が切れても消えないディスプレイって？電子ペーパーを使ってみた！](https://dotstud.io/blog/using-e-paper-module/)
  [Raspberry Pi で電子ペーパーを点けてみる (e-Paper )](https://qiita.com/jp_yen/items/98d92aad45bac80d7d1a)

などの対応をしてください。
何かの操作で置き換わったりするようですね。[system fontが汎用CJKになっていた](https://matoken.org/blog/2018/05/21/system-font-was-a-general-cjk/)

※ ご質問の症状はフォントファイルのインストールで解決したようです。

---

<sup>この投稿は @kunif さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55313/#comment59359_55313)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>